# Im trying to make a write to text file in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this code but doesn't seem to be doing anything so I am a bit stuck

```
const string sPath = "movieAdd.txt";
System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count ==1)
{
     foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
     {
          SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
     }
     SaveFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: what is happening currently? any errors?

Comment: he said. It's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as it is writes lines only when exactly one entry in the list is selected. I'm unsure whether this is what you want, considering you're trying to write one line per selected item. You may want to rewrite your code to the following, which allows for more than one row to be selected. Also, the file is closed in any case in the following code.

```
const string sPath = "movieAdd.txt";
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath))
    {
        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Another issue may be you don't have an explicit path in your `sPath` variable. This may cause problems, depending on the current working directory, which may be different from the directory the executable resides in! It would be safer to add a directory explicitly, like this:

```
const string sPath = @"C:\temp\movieAdd.txt";
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath))
    {
        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx before it wasnt doing anything now it has thank you i have seen what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pointing anywhere ...
Try `const string sPath = @"C:\movieAdd.txt";`
or something like that.

Even better, use the `Path` methods to create it, or something like:

```
const string sPath = @"c:\movieAdd.txt";
    List<string> strings_to_write = new List<string>():
        if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count ==1)
        {
            foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                strings_to_write.Add(item);
            }


    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sPath, strings_to_write);
```